# Why is my header not printing?

Tags: perl

I have a task of printing a text file (containing the headers and several rows). I managed to write a program to print the several rows in the text file. But I couldn't make my code print the table headers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'c73p1avrfusevrmtop.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my $row = <$fh>;

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    print "$row\n";
}
```

---

I have 8 columns x 7 and the last column is empty. I want to print my rows under each of the column aligned. I'm sorry am not able to attach an image since it requires 10 reputation.

I apologize for that mistake. This is the table i was referring about.

```
Type            Name                               Rev Id      ZZZ ID  IP     Group        Date Released  AA Category  Project IDs
 xxxxxComponent xyz_abc_1234LDO_c7rp1avrusevrmdtop  xxxx_2_5    99ccccc1      ABC- RIP-xxxxx    2015-05-03 6:59:09  xxxx    
 xxxxxComponent xyz_abc_1234LDO_c7rp1avrusevrmdtop  xxxx_2_5    99ccccc1    ABC  RIP xxxxx  2015-05-03 6:59:09  xxxx
 xxxxxComponent xyz_abc_1234LDO_c7rp1avrusevrmdtop  xxxx_2_5    99ccccc1    ABC RIP xxxxx   2015-05-03 6:59:09  xxxx
```

Comment: I assume you are also processing the text file inside the `while` loop, otherwise you might as well just use the `cat` function: `cat c73p1avrfusevrmtop.txt`

Comment: Is that a tab-delimited file or does it have fixed-width columns?

Answer (score 4):

You simply forgot to print it. In my fix below, I use a separate variable for the header (i.e. the first line), simply to document why I'm not printing it in the loop.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 # Create a file handle for the input file
 my $filename = 'c73p1avrfusevrmtop.txt';
 open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename) 
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

 # print header
 my $header = <$fh>;
 print $header;

 # print rows
 while (my $row = <$fh>) {
     chomp $row;
     print "$row\n";
 }
```

---

Here is the same code in the format that I would prefer:

```
 #!/bin/env perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use autodie; # so I don't have to use the 'open or die' idiom

 # Create a file handle for the input file
 my $filename = 'c73p1avrfusevrmtop.txt';
 open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename);

 # print header
 my $header = readline $fh;
 print $header;             # note it still has a newline

 # print rows
 while (my $row = readline $fh) {
     chomp $row;
     print "$row\n";
 }
```

Comment: I got my table to be printed. But my headers are not aligned with the table rows. How can I change my code a bit to print rows under each headers in an aligned format.

Comment: @rajal2 Please edit your question to show us the first few lines of your file (or even better, a sample file). Also, please edit your question to show us what the output should be like for the data you've shown.

Comment: @AndyLester I feel `readline` is much more self-explanatory than `<>`. I've taught several introduction to Perl workshops and find it easier to teach them `readline` and then later explain that `<>` is the shortcut version (instead of the other way around).

Comment: Why am I not getting any response to my questions ? Was I buggin you guys so much

Comment: @rjl I just now looked through all of your questions and it looked to me that they were answered either by an explicit answer or in a comment.

Comment: Yes it makes much more sense to me now than earlier. I could dissect code and find out where the bug and ask more specific questions. Do you know how I could reopen one of my questions not for public comments but for my reference purposes?